# PHP Curl Send and Download - Big files

Tags: php, curl, cron

I have a PHP function using Curl that get as a response an encoded ZIP file. This file is being download and saved on our server.
This script is called with a CRONJOB.
When I try to download a 1Mb file, absolute no issue.
When I try to download a 15Mb file, if I call the script on a navigator, no issue ! If i call the script via the CRONJOB, then the file simply are not saved at all on our server (no error on the error_log). Is there a timeout or something specifically trough the CRONJOB ?
I would say trough navigator it takes something like 10 sec for the file to be downloaded.

Regards,

```
function saveRemoteFile($url, $token, $type ) {
  // API Request
  

  // initialize cURL
  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'accept: */*',
    'Authorization: Bearer '.$token
  ));
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 400);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT ,0);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, '');
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  
  // Execute cURL and store the response in a variable
  $file = curl_exec($ch);
  
  // Get the Header Size
  $header_size = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE);
  // Get the Header from response
  $header = substr($file, 0, $header_size);
  // Get the Body from response
  $body = substr($file, $header_size);
  // Explode Header rows into an array
  $header_items = explode("\n", $header);
  // Close cURL handler
  curl_close($ch);
  
  // find the filname in the headers.
  $file_name = "BIHR.zip";
  // Check header response, if HTTP response is not 200, then display the error.
  if(!preg_match('/200/', $header_items[0])){
      echo '<pre>'.print_r($header_items[0], true).'</pre>';
      exit();
  } else {
      // Check header response, if HTTP response is 200, then proceed further.
  
      // Set the header for PHP to tell it, we would like to download a file
      header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
      header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
      header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
      header('Expires: 0');
      header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
      header('Pragma: public');
      header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$file_name);
  
    $destdir = '/******/file';
    file_put_contents($destdir.'/'.date('y').date('m').date('d').'bihr_'.$type.'.zip',$body);
  
      exit;
  }
  }
```

Comment: Does the cronjob actually run? Does this script work on the command line?

Comment: Possible file system permission error. Is the cron ran by a user that has permissions to save files? You could try to log your cron with `>>` to a file, like so `* * * * * php some-file.php >> output.txt` and see if there are some errors.

Comment: @shingo yes it run perfectly as when I try to download smaller file trough the same cronjob, work awesome :)

Comment: @Kipras I tried to log the output, I have an output with some information (echo of previous request) but absolute no error

Comment: You can try to see what `file_put_contents()` returns. Should return bytes written or false on failure. https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php#refsect1-function.file-put-contents-returnvalues

Comment: I **infer** from your descritpion that the script (CRONJOB is a really bad name) can successfully download a 1Mb file. If that is so, then your descrription of events is VERY improbable. Go back and check your methodology.

Comment: @Kipras Thanks for your help.
The file_put_content output the bytes written indeed.. 
Script called via navigator : 1Mb file -> 1400518 / 15Mb file -> 15439491
Script called via CRONJOB : 1Mb file -> 1400518 / 15Mb file -> No output
That mean the script stop before the end of this function ?

Comment: You've only metioned it works for small file, I can assume the cronjob has run, then how about run on the command line to download a large file?

Answer (score 0):

After investigation, the issue was about php.ini memory_limit variable.

Went from memory_limit = 32M to memory_limit = 64M and everything is now working perfectly.

Still I do not get the difference between launching the script mannualy (I mean copy/paste the PHP script url on Chrome) and lauching the script via a CRON Job that could explain that manually 32M was sufficient, and CRON Job needed more ....

If anyone can explain, I would learn something.

Regards,

Edit : When you open mannualy a script trough the navigator it uses the local php.ini file. When you open a script trough CRON Job it uses the master value php.ini of the server. So in my cas the memory_limit wasn't the same...
Learn something today